# Request.UrlReferrer not working in IE7

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this following code:

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        {
            if (Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.ToLowerInvariant() == "/test/content.htm")
            {
                postbacklink = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Replace("/TEST/Content.htm", "/Testing.aspx?")  + Request.QueryString;
            }
            else
            {
                postbacklink = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
            }
        }
        ExtendedLoanView.PostbackLink = postbacklink;
```

Now this page can be accessed by two different locations. Which means this code:

```
 postbacklink = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Replace("/TEST/Content.htm", "/Test.aspx?")  + Request.QueryString;
```

can only work with one page (Test.aspx) and is hard coded. So in IE7 Request.UrlReferrer shows me this:

```
Request.UrlReferrer = {http://Testing:12345/PPP/Content.htm}
```

Whereas in IE8+ I am getting this value:

```
Request.UrlReferrer = {http://Testing:12345/PPP/TestingPage.aspx?Name=Xyz&Address=123 YYY
```

How should I solve this issue? Its been bugging me for past month.

Comment: The code you've posted and the problem you've described really don't necessarily seem related. What is 'postbacklink' used for? What does the URL in it being hard-coded have to do with IE7 showing you something different for the referrer? That doesn't seem... possible.

Comment: postbacklink is just a 'var' variable. Nothing much! IE7 is giving me content.htm and from this I cannot see that which page should I show to the user. Eg, If you are on Test.aspx and clicking on a button, then from Request.UrlReferrer I am checking which page should I show to you: Test1.aspx or Test2.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely advice not to base your logic on request information (not anymore than user entered values). The thing is that it **will** be different across browsers, and it is really hackable.

If you still need to pass information from client to server, make sure to have those validated. If you need those to stay in sync and have valid information, do not rely on what the browsers give you, but set it yourself and then take it from a place in the request you did set (for example, a hidden input, a control, a variable on the viewstate, or whatever allows the technology you're using).

Most sites handle the situation you're trying to solve by passing the destination URL in the URL itself, in a query parameter. For example:

http://www.example.com/Login.aspx?returnUrl=/TEST/content.htm

**EDIT:** I do realize that everything you send to the client is very hackable anyway, but if you set it yourself, it's easier for you to validate that it hasn't been tampered with. An example is the ViewState validation methods.

Comment: So you are suggesting that ViewState is the way to go for? Like I can create ViewState and check on the other page that which page its coming from. Or I can create hidden form inputs...

Comment: @Raj I don't fully know your necessities on this, but depending on them, you could use `PreviousPage` and base yourself on the class type (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx), or use the ViewState in that PreviousPage, or, as well, use hidden inputs as you said.
If it's just to know which page is it coming from and they are always postbacks, I would use `PreviousPage`.

Comment: Thanks man! I will try PreviousPage and will test it in IE7 browser else, I will go hidden input route.